# How to make ENTER do go to the selected type or method when using Ensime global search with Emacs --no-window?

Tags: scala, emacs, console, ensime

I'm using Ensime 2.10.0-0.9.8.9 with emacs 23.4.1, and I'm using emacs with --no-window parameter in the gnome terminal (v3.6.1). When I try to search for a scala type or method in my project with global search command C-c C-v v and then press ENTER to go to the selected item, it does not, but just enters a new line in the *ensime-search* buffer.

The thing is, when I try to do the same thing in normal emacs (without --no-window), all is fine...

Does someone know how to make it work with --no-window too ?

PS: please, don't answer: "just use emacs without --no-window"... :)

Comment: I had similar issues with some bindings in --no-window mode. This was caused by the terminal that had some own key shorcuts. In my case `C-8` was `DEL`. In your case, maybe there is something badly assigned to `RET` or `<return>` (even `<kp-enter>`). Try looking at `C-h b` or the Terminal shortcuts.

Comment: @makeMonday thx, for your answer. It has nothing to do with the terminal shortcuts (I tried with terminator, it is the same). But I looked at the emacs key bindings and I found that `RET` is binded to `scala-newline`, `<kp-enter>` and `<return>` binded to `RET`. I looked at the ensime-search.el and found this : `(define-key map [(return)] 'ensime-search-choose-current-result)`. I don't know how to fixe the return binding, so I added a new binding to this last function, for now.

Comment: @ygu, do 'C-h k RET`, in `ensime-search-buffer`, it popup a window with help about the command run when you press enter, what does it output?

Comment: @IqbalAnsari it outputs : "RET runs the command newline, which is an interactive compiled Lisp function.", so not really what I expected, indeed.

Comment: @ygu I am just guessing switch to the `ensime-search-buffer` and do `M-: (define-key map [(return)] 'ensime-search-choose-current-result) RET`, then try pressing `enter` on a search result

Comment: Oops there was a typo in my previous comment do `M-: (define-key ensime-search-mode-map [(return)] 'ensime-search-choose-current-result) RET`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found out how to solve this problem. I added the following binding in *ensime_2.10.0-0.9.8.9/elisp/ensime-search.el* :

```
(define-key map (kbd "RET") 'ensime-search-choose-current-result)
```

in the definition of function *ensime-search-mode-map*.

PS: as mentionned by Iqbal Ansari, it is better to add the binding in the init file :

```
(define-key ensime-search-mode-map (kbd "RET") 'ensime-search-choose-current-result)
```

Comment: Hi @ygu, do NOT edit the file, you edits will lost on updates. As far as I see the file (ensime-search.el) already has the line you have posted. If does not have the line, you can add the following to your init file `(define-key ensime-search-mode-map [(return)] 'ensime-search-choose-current-result)`

Comment: @IqbalAnsari you're right, the line you quoted is already in ensime-search.el, but it does nothing in 'no-window' mode, whereas the line I posted does. But you're right, it's better to add it in the init file. I edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, for partially fixing this I guess you can rebind the `RET` key just in scala-mode (or ensime). For that use:

```
(add-hook 'scala-mode-hook
      (lambda () (local-set-key (kbd "RET") 'newline)))
```

Anyway, I say partially because I am not sure of what `scala-newline` does, so maybe there is some functionality that you may lose. You can try and see if that's ok for you.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: thx, but I'm not sure what you're expecting with this code. You seem to bind key RET to function newline (or scala-newline I assume). What I need is to bind key RET to function ensime-search-choose-current-result, and not in scala-mode, but only in the ensime-search-buffer. Nevertheless, thanks for indicating how to capture RET key.

Comment: Well, I was just guessing, maybe `scala-newline` (which definition I couldn't find :-/ ) is doing something wrong. So maybe assigning it back to `newline` (its default binding) would make it work as it should, at least in that case (not doing a `newline` in a *minibuffer*). I had a look at `ensime-search-choose-current-result`, but I didn't see anything weird. The only "problem" I've seen was that `scala-newline`.